# Having issues with regex sub function in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, text-analysis

I am trying to remove symbols like \x92, \xa0 etc from a text that I have downloaded from website and parsed using BeautifulSoup. Then I see that I have these symbols (encoding ) everywhere. I am using `re.sub(r'[^\x00-x7F]',' ',txt)`
to remove these symbols from my `txt`, but I noticed that I have lost each occurrence of `y`. For example: 'Security' became 'Securit' etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You missed ``\`` before `x7F`. `r'[^\x00-\x7F]'`. A `0-x` makes a range from `0` to `x`, so `y` and `z` will be matched and removed.

Comment: Sorry, the range is from `\x00` to `x`. Use `re.DEBUG`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/stTDi3). It shows that your pattern matches all but `range (0, 120)`, `literal 55` and `literal 70`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did resolve the issue (and a big headache). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The (erroneous) regular expression `r'[^\x00-x7F]'` probably should be `r'[^\x00-\x7F]'` (note an additional backslash).

As you have written, it contains the set *not* in NUL through `x`.  So `y` and subsequent ascii codes are missing.